# Send a push notification per day with Parse.com

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have an English Dictionary application. I want to send one word with its explanation per day via Parse.com Push Notification. The push notification will be delivered at certain time (example: at 23.00 pm).

I guess its to do this with Parse Cloud Code. But how can I do it?

Comment: Dear Colorist; You can use Parse Jobs where you can schedule jobs  to predetermined time and send push notification as a main logic. Bu be careful that Parse Jobs has time out limits. You can read the background jobs in following link. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

If you are studying its [parse Push Notification documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/Android) There is already mention that `Sending scheduled push notifications is not currently supported by the Android SDK`

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per @kingspeech s comment, I imagine iOS and Android are the receiving apps but you can certainly schedule the push from a Parse job or another server using Rest

Comment: i agree with @Paulw11 and kingspeech . i am cheking the documentations